# create tables/rows in ram using sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, ram

I remember once i had temporary data used on a webpage. I used php and mysql to create a table that stored visitors ips and the port they requested. I didnt care how long they lasted because after 10mins or an hour the data would no longer be relevant. I cant remember how i did it but using sqlite instead...

How do i create a table for rows meant to be stored in ram only for a limited amount of time (a few minutes) using sqlite? Using C# .NET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following connection string: `Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True`. It is important to note that a memory database exists as long as the connection remains open.